# How to disable CheckBox inside ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, wpf-controls

I have ListView with one column that contains checkboxes

```
 <ListView Height="164" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="DataGridCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="4" />
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="40">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductName}" Header="Product Name" Width="120" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

How can I disable checkboxes from code?
Is it possible to do that with something like: `window1.checkBox1.IsEnabled = false;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the CheckBox.IsEnabled to a property from the model class.

Xaml:

```
...
<DataTemplate>
     <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"/>
</DataTemplate>
...
```

Code behind:

```
//Your object used in List for ListViews ItemsSource
...
public bool IsEnabled{get;set;}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to access a control inside `DataTemplate` through code but that would not be the right way or approach. You shouldn't do this. You should instead use the bindings to disable or enable the checkbox inside ListView

Answer (score 0):

Make a binding to some Property (bool) that represents the isChecked state:

```
...
<DataTemplate>
  <CheckBox Style="..." IsChecked="{Binding AmIChecked}" />
</DataTemplate>
...
```